# TCP tuning for DPM on Windows 2012

Tags: windows, tcp, wide-area-network, scdpm

I've got a pair of servers on opposite ends of a fast (1-10Gb depending on the server) but higher latency (40-60ms) link.

Various network tuning options have been set resulting in iperf3 yielding appropriately high transfer rates across the link. However, it doesn't appear that DPM sees the same performance increase from the tuning.

There are information sites for doing tcp tuning with 2010 specifically related to DPM on 2010:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff634226.aspx

However, those options are no longer supported with 2012 as far as I know. Is anyone aware of any DPM specific tuning for tcp window sizes or other tuning options for performance on higher latency WAN links?